# How to hide inactive items on a table by default

Tags: filter, data-tables

I'm working on a table where each item has several attributes, one of which is "Status".

Status can be: Pending, active, expired, deleted, canceled, etc.

I wish that the **default state of the table would only show active items.**

I thought of adding a check box, but there is a link between the filter on the status column and the check box and I think it is strange to load a table with a filter active.

How can I keep the column filter and have a clear and fast way to show all items?
Keep in mind that inactive is a group of statuses.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a graphical or code solution?

Comment: @Danielillo - a UX solution, I wouldn't call it "graphical" since it is more about the behavior then how it looks